# Create macOS 10.12 VM on VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, vmware

Can someone let me know how can I create a macOS 10.12 VM for VMware Fusion? I am not able to find the ISO of macOS 10.12.

In app store I am seeing *macOS High Sierra* which I am not interested in.

Environment:-

- VMware Fusion - 8.5.8
- OS in which Fusion Running - macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macOS 10.12.(x) iso doesn't exist. To install macOS 10.12 in a VM on **your** host you either have to use an existing macOS 10.12 installer app on your Mac or a share, download the macOS 10.12 installer app from the Apple App Store which requires the app to be listed in your purchase list or install it using the recovery partition.

On most Apple App Store accounts the Sierra installer seems to have vanished after High Sierra was published even if Sierra was "purchased" in the past, so you have to log-in and check your purchase list.

If the Sierra installer is still available in your account, download it and either [create a dmg/iso](https://github.com/rtrouton/create_macos_vm_install_dmg) or use the app itself as installer source (> Create a custom virtual machine).

---

To install Sierra in a VM on **your** host (with Sierra  installed) you can also use the recovery partition of your Mac:

Open VMware Fusion and create a new machine (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

In the new window choose: *Install OS X from the recovery partition*

[image: Select the Installation Method]

Save the VM to an appropriate folder, configure it (number of CPUs/RAM/network interface etc.) and start the installation afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for a two step set up, you can start downloading and then installing [OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886) from the App Store as a VMware Fusion VM.

After you have installed OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan, you should be able to download the macOS 10.12 Sierra install app, which you then can use to do a clean install in a new VMware Fusion VM.