# Creating High Sierra as VM under VMware Fusion

Tags: high-sierra, virtualization, vmware

I need to create a VM for macOS High Sierra to run with VMware Fusion. I would prefer this VM be created *from* my existing MacBook running High Sierra (a real, physical device), but that's not essential.

I have a current version (v 11.5.5) of VMware Fusion on my new-ish MacBook running Catalina - this is where I'd like to run my High Sierra VM. The MacBook running High Sierra also has VMware Fusion, but it's an old copy that can't be updated any longer.

### What I've done so far:

1. I have read [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301825/create-macos-10-12-vm-on-vmware-fusion) which is related to my question.
2. I have contacted VMware technical support, asking basically the same question: How can I create a VM of my MacBook running High Sierra?
3. I have attempted to create a .dmg file of the HD in my High Sierra Mac using [CCC](https://bombich.com/)

### Results & observations:

1. For reasons I don't understand, my physical MacBook running High Sierra does not have a Recovery partition - perhaps it was not picked up during a previous upgrade to the HDD/SSD. Consequently, that option seems to be unavailable?

   I d/l a file named `macOSUpdCombo10.13.6.dmg` from an Apple support site (don't recall the URL). However, when opening that file in VMware Fusion, instead of High Sierra, I get what appears to be an installation procedure. It was not clear **where** this was going to be installed, so I abandoned it. *Has anyone else used this file to create a High Sierra VM under VMware Fusion?*

   [This Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301825/create-macos-10-12-vm-on-vmware-fusion) has a link to a utility named [`create_macos_vm_install_dmg`](https://github.com/rtrouton/create_macos_vm_install_dmg) which claims to "*prepare macOS installer disk images for use with ... VMware Fusion...*". I have not tried this utility, but am willing to try it - however I would much prefer to hear from someone who has used it successfully before I do. *Will this utility create a (dmg) file that VMware Fusion can open and run a macOS High Sierra VM?*
2. VMware tech support advised of availability of a suitable file at [this location (hackintosh?)](https://www.hackintosh.computer/199/direct-download-macos/). Before they sent me the link, the VMware tech support person asked me to recite a disclaimer during our phone conversation. This made me a little nervous... when I visited the site, I got a little more nervous :)  *Has anyone used VM files from this source - are they OK?*
3. I've tried to create a `.dmg` backup file using [CCC](https://bombich.com/). That has been particularly confusing - partly because it seems to have wrecked the network drive location where Time Machine keeps backups for my MacBook running Catalina. I'm afraid I am just not smart enough to use CCC.

### How Should I Proceed?

I'm probably a little frustrated at this point. My experience with cloning machines in VMware was 3-4 years ago in a MS Windows environment - it was *dead simple* - literally a one-or-two-mouse-click operation. And I've used VMware quite a bit in a Mac environment, but recently that's been limited to virtualization of Linux OS... also dead simple to do.

All that aside, I need to get this (*virtualization of macOS High Sierra*) done for a number of reasons. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: @bmike: You asked me to let you know if I posted this as a new question.

Comment: The macOSUpdCombo10.13.6.dmg is not the same thing as a macOS Installer, e.g. Install macOS High Sierra.app , it's just an update to be applied to an already running macOS High Sierra install.

Comment: Is there some reason you do not just create a **macOS High Sierra** virtual machine and then use **Migration Assistant** to move **User Data** and **Applications** from the physical machine to the virtual machine?

Comment: @user3439894: "just create a macOS High Sierra virtual machine...?" - IIUYQ: No - I thought I covered that with "but that's not essential" in my question. But that's the problem... how to "just create a macOS High Sierra VM"

Comment: You do not need any third-party utilities to do any of this! All you need a copy of **Install macOS High Sierra.app** from which you'll make a **macOS High Sierra USB Installer** to boot the **MacBook** running **macOS High Sierra** and create a **DMG** _image_ of the  e.g. **Macintosh HD** using **Disk Utility**, then restore it to the virtual machine's HDD. **VMware Fusion** will use the **Install macOS High Sierra.app** to create a temporary **macOS High Sierra Installer** to a vHDD, which you'd use **Disk Utility** from there to restore the **DMG** _image_. It's really just that simple!

Comment: Obviously you also need an external **USB** drive large enough to write the **DMG** _image_ to.

Comment: A VMWare tech sent you to hackintosh.computer to download something!?! What on earth? No, please don't download from there. I'm a Hackintosh user, and _I_ avoid that site.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: Ha ha - yeah, it *looks* a little sketchy. But not to worry - as my role model says, ["New s**t has come to light man".](https://youtu.be/DUEvYHnCvJo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **VMware Fusion Professional Version 11.5.3** on a **MacBook Pro** running **macOS High Sierra**, I did the following to create a new **macOS High Sierra** *virtual machine*:

1. Open **VMware Fusion**.
2. Press **⌘N** (**File** > **New**).
3. From **Finder**, drag an drop the **Install macOS High Sierra.app** *application bundle* onto the **Select the Installation Method** *window* of **VMware Fusion**.
4. On the **Create a New Virtual Machine** *window*, click the **Continue** *button*.
5. On the **Finish** *window*, click the **Customize Settings** *button*.
6. In the **Save As:** *sheet*, follow thru as appropriate to then click the **Save** *button*.
7. Wait for the **Creating installation medium… This may take a few minutes.** *sheet* to disappear, as this then shows the *window* for the *virtual machine* and its **Settings** *window*.
8. In the **Settings** *window* make the appropriate changes, i.e., **Processor & Memory**, **Hard Disk (SATA)**, not **Hard Disk 2 (SATA)** as that's the temporary installer **vHDD**, etc.

- Note: If the default **vHDD** is not large enough you'll need to delete the default one, not resize it, and add a new right-sized one in its place. You will then also need to partition and format it (actually erase it) using **Disk Utility** from the **maxOS Utilities** *window* before you select **Install macOS** during the install process.
- After making the appropriate changes to the settings, close the **Settings** *window*.

9. Click the **play** *button* on the *virtual machine* window and the **macOS** install process begins.

When you get to the **macOS Utilities** *window*, if you added a larger **vHDD**, select **Disk Utility** and click the **Continue** *button*, then preform the following steps:

1. Select: **VMware Virtual SATA Hard Disk Media**
2. Click the **Erase** *button*.
3. On the **Erase ...** *sheet*, change **Name:** from **Untitled** to e.g.: **Macintosh HD**
4. On the **Erase ...** *sheet*, click the **Erase** *button*.
5. Click the **Done** *button*.
6. Close **Disk Utility**.

Otherwise, select **Install macOS** and click the **Continue** *button*.

Continue to follow thru as appropriate with the install of **macOS** until the install of the **OS** is finished.

At this point you should now have a new **macOS High Sierra** *virtual machine* which you can choose to the finish clean building by manually installing the *apps* you need/want, and then restore your *data* from backup, or another option is to try using **Migration Assistant** instead.

---

As a side note, before you start the install, I'd make a copy of the *virtual machine's* configuration file and a copy of **Hard Disk 2 (SATA)** the temporary installer **vHDD** as you might find it useful if you choose to go the cloning route. These file are found within the *document bundle* of the *virtual machine*, e.g.,:

- macOS 10.13.6.vmx
- Temporary Installation Source Disk.dmg
- Temporary Installation Source Disk.vmdk

---

## NOTES:

As a result of issues the OP was having, as discussed in the comment thread, I've come up with a *workaround* that works as tested.

---

**Before the Install:**

If you're having an issue with **VMware Fusion** creating the *installation media* you can try the following *workaround*.  This assumes the copy of the **Install macOS High Sierra.app** *application bundle* is not actually damaged.

First, make a **macOS USB Installer** following the directions in: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

For **macOS High Sierra** you'll need an **8 GB USB Flash Drive** formatted as **Mac OS Extended** with nothing valuable on it as it will be erased during the creation process.

The following *command* shows the *syntax*, e.g.:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

After creating the **macOS USB Installer** you'll use `vmware-rawdiskCreator` to create a **raw disk VMDK** of the **macOS USB Installer** to manually add to the *configuration file* of the **macOS High Sierra** *virtual machine* following the directions in: [Creating a raw disk VMDK and adding it to the Virtual machine in Fusion (2097401)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2097401)

**What I did:**

```
% mount
 /dev/disk4s1 on /Volumes/Install macOS High Sierra (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
# Relevant line above from the mount command, other lines omitted for brevity.

% vmware-rawdiskCreator print /dev/disk4
  Nr      Start       Size Type Id Sytem                   
 -- ---------- ---------- ---- -- ------------------------
 1          2   15633406 BIOS AF HFS+

% vmware-rawdiskCreator create /dev/disk4 1 'Install macOS High Sierra' lsilogic
% ls -l *.vmdk
% -rw-------  1 me  staff  32256 Jun 14 17:34 Install macOS High Sierra-pt.vmdk
% -rw-------  1 me  staff    772 Jun 14 17:34 Install macOS High Sierra.vmdk

# The path to vmware-rawdiskCreator omitted for brevity.
# /dev/disk4s1 is what the USB Installer is on my system and will vary from system to system.
```

I moved the `Install macOS High Sierra-pt.vmdk` and `Install macOS High Sierra.vmdk` *files* to within the *document bundle* of the *virtual machine* and edited the *configuration file*, e.g. `macOS 10.13.6.vmx`, adding the following lines:

```
sata0:2.present = "TRUE"
sata0:2.fileName = "Install macOS High Sierra.vmdk"
sata0:2.deviceType = "rawDisk"
suspend.disabled = "TRUE"
```

I also edited `bios.hddOrder` to be: `bios.hddOrder = "sata0:2"`

When starting the *virtual machine* with a **raw disk VMDK** you'll be prompted with a *password dialog box* stating, **VMware Fusion requires administrative privileges for accessing Boot Camp disks.**; however this is a generic message displayed for any **raw disk VMDK**, not just when running a **Boot Camp** install as a *virtual machine*.

After the install is finished the *lines* added to the *configuration file* can be removed and reset `bios.hddOrder` to, e.g.,: `bios.hddOrder = "sata0:0"`

---

**During the Install:**

If your copy of the **Install macOS High Sierra.app** *application bundle* was downloaded before **October 24, 2019**, when Apple's security certificates used to sign software expired, you will get the error message **This copy of macOS High Sierra application is damaged, and can't be used to install macOS** during the install process after selecting **Install macOS** and clicking the **Continue** *button*.

The *workaround*, assuming the copy of the **Install macOS High Sierra.app** *application bundle* is actually not damaged, is to temporally disconnect the **Network Adapter** of the *virtual machine*, so it cannot communicate with an **NTP Time Server**, and temporally set the **date** to any *date* before **October 24, 2019**.

This can be done before selecting **Install macOS** and clicking the **Continue** *button* by using **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu using, e.g., `date 102300019` and then close **Terminal** and proceed as normal.

After the initial install is finished the **date** can be set to its proper *date* and the **Network Adapter** of the *virtual machine* re-connected.

---

Comment: This looks like a very good answer. I'm going to try it, but I've got to solve another  problem first: I have VMware Fusion (not Pro). Two things I've just learned: 1. Fusion v. 11 doesn't run on High Sierra - Fusion *Pro* v. 11 **does**. And comparing the two products [here](https://is.gd/YvGL2O), I see that the few diffs between the products fall right into the area of my question. $120 for the upgrade! Wow - good thing I'm filthy rich  LOL.

Comment: @Seamus, What's the other problem you need to solve first? Both **VMware Fusion 11** and **VMware Fusion Pro 11** run on **macOS High Sierra** or later.

Comment: Not in my experience (already tried), and [not according to VMware](https://imgur.com/gallery/PzG81fa)

Comment: @Seamus, In your first comment you said "1. Fusion v. 11 doesn't run on High Sierra - Fusion Pro v. 11 does." and 11.5.5 is not the same as 11. Regardless though, are you not running this on **macOS Catalina** anyway, which makes this a moot point?

Comment: @Seamus, What's the other problem you need to solve first?

Comment: Your answer begins with this: "Version 11.5.3 on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra," I'm very literal you see... But chill, please - I can try it on Catalina.

Comment: The "other problem"? Spending $120 of course!

Comment: @Seamus, My answer starts off with that just to show what version and OS I preformed this under but using the Pro version is not a requirement to do this!  In your OP you said "I have a current version (v 11.5.5) of VMware Fusion on my new-ish MacBook running Catalina - this is where I'd like to run my High Sierra VM." -- These directions should work there as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109326/discussion-between-seamus-and-user3439894).

Comment: "...is to temporally disconnect the Network Adapter of the virtual machine, so it can communicate with an NTP Time Server" - I think you meant to say "so it _**can't**_ communicate".

Comment: @Vikki - formerly Sean, Yes, it was a typo and now fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393792/149366) is the accepted answer, and AFAIK, it is also a correct answer. However, I need to say that I have not actually worked through the entire procedure given in the answer. I got *bogged down* in the details of using VMware's `vmware-rawdiskCreator`, and could not complete the procedure.

If you care to read through the extensive comments following the accepted answer, you may conclude that the latest versions of macOS Catalina (10.15.5) and VMware Fusion (11.5.5) made creation of a macOS VM [*arduous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arduous) at best. I do not understand why this is so, but I believe that it is *unnecessarily difficult* due to decisions made by Apple and VMware. I say this because it **is** easy using older versions of the software.

My primary purpose for posting this **alternative answer** is to describe how I created a `macOS High Sierra VM` that runs under VMware Fusion (11.5.5) on my macOS Catalina machine (10.15.5). It may be an easier approach than the accepted answer, but it requires an additional Mac with an older version of macOS, and - at least in my case - an older version of VMware Fusion. That said, here goes:

### An Alternative Approach

#### Step 1.

The initial challenge is to obtain a *full* copy (*> 5 GB file*) of the 'app file'/*application bundle*: `Install macOS High Sierra.app`. Here's an ["official source"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) for this file on Apple's website.

#### Step 2.

Once you have this file (`Install macOS High Sierra.app`), it should be located on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 that also has a copy of VMware Fusion ver. 10. **Note that *other combinations* of macOS and VMware Fusion may also work - I am only reporting what I used.**

#### Step 3.

Make a High Sierra VM in VMware Fusion by selecting `File, New...` from the menu bar, and then drag-and-drop the file `Install macOS High Sierra.app` into the VMware Fusion dialog box. Follow the guided process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click the `Finish` button to begin creating the High Sierra VM. When the process has completed, you will see the new VM listed, and you may select it, and start it. The VM will start in a new window.

[image]

[image]

#### Step 4.

Finally, copy the `.vmwarevm` file from the High Sierra Mac (the real, physical one) to the Catalina Mac. Once you have the file positioned where you want it, *right-click* on it, and select the option to open the file with VMware Fusion.

That's it. I'm considering writing an Epilogue to this saga to document some of the road-blocks encountered, and my questions regarding why this process was made so difficult. That's for another day - I'm officially *burned out* on Catalina and VMware for now.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393792/149366) is the accepted answer, and AFAIK, it is also a correct answer. However, I need to say that I have not actually worked through the entire procedure given in that answer. I got *bogged down* in the details of using VMware's `vmware-rawdiskCreator`, and could not complete the procedure. I previously created an alternative approach [(***first alternative approach***) to the accepted answer which is here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393978/149366). This answer - the one that follows - is a ***second alternative approach*** for meeting the objective:

---

#### The Objective: Create a `macOS High Sierra VM` that runs under VMware Fusion (11.5.5) on macOS Catalina (10.15.5)

**Note:** This may be an easier approach than the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393792/149366). It may also be easier than this [earlier alternative answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393978/149366) as it **does not require** an additional Mac with an older version of macOS. The following procedure can be completed from the *target macOS Catalina 10.15.5 host*. This simplification is enabled by a GitHub repo aptly named [`create_macos_vm_install_dmg`](https://github.com/rtrouton/create_macos_vm_install_dmg).

## Yet Another Alternative Approach:

### Prerequisites:

1. A local copy of the script: `create_macos_vm_install_dmg.sh`, available [from the author's GitHub repo](https://github.com/rtrouton/create_macos_vm_install_dmg)
2. A copy of Apple's current High Sierra installer `Install macOS High Sierra.app` - which **may** be available on [Apple's website here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

### Create the VM:

#### Step 1:

With both prerequisite files located in your Desktop folder (`~/Desktop`), run the following commands in `Terminal`:

```
% cd ~/Desktop
% chmod 755 create_macos_vm_install_dmg.sh
% sudo ./create_macos_vm_install_dmg.sh "./Install macOS High Sierra.app" ~/Desktop
```

The script will ask: `Do you also want an .iso disk image?`. Reply to the prompt from the keyboard with: `1` <kbd>return</kbd>. The script will post its progress to the `Terminal` window, ending successfully with this:

```
-- Building process complete.
-- Built .dmg disk image file is available at /Users/youruser/Desktop/macOS_10136_installer.dmg
-- Built .iso disk image file is available at /Users/youruser/Desktop/macOS_10136_installer.iso
```

#### Step 2:

- Start the `VMware Fusion` app
- Select `File, New...` from the VMware menu bar
- Drag and drop the ISO file created in Step 1 into the window titled **Select the Installation Method**

From this point, the rest is bog-standard for creating a VM in VMware Fusion - consult the VMware Fusion documentation if you have any questions. The ISO file will be used to install and create a High Sierra VM on macOS Catalina. You will be prompted for location, language, etc - same as when you set up macOS on a new machine. The entire process took about 12-15 minutes on on my Macbook Pro.

And that's it - I've attached some screenshots from the procedure below as a visual reference.

---

#### 0. Initial Error: VMware 11.5.5 on macOS 10.15.5 w/ `Install macOS High Sierra.app`:

**Some notes:**

- The initial failure...
- VMware ver 11.5.5
- macOS 10.15.5 (Catalina)
- Application bundle: `Install macOS High Sierra.app`
- This **will work** with (e.g.) macOS 10.15.4 & VMware ver 11.5.3
- Cause of this failure remains unknown at present

[image: VMware Fusion error]

#### 1. Successful High Sierra Installation - VMware 11.5.5 w/ `macOS_10136_installer.iso`

[image: Step 1 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 2. Successful High Sierra Installation - Choose OS

[image: Step 2 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 3. Successful High Sierra Installation - Finish Configuration

[image: Step 3 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 4. Successful High Sierra Installation - Commence VM Installation

[image: Step 4 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 5. Successful High Sierra Installation - High Sierra Install Options

[image: Step 5 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 6. Successful High Sierra Installation - Select Installer

[image: Step 6 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 7. Successful High Sierra Installation - Begin Installation

[image: Step 7 of Successful VM Installation]

#### 8. Successful High Sierra Installation - Installation Complete

[image]

Successful Creation: High Sierra VM under VMware 11.5.5 on macOS 10.15.5 w/ `Install macOS High Sierra.app` and `create_macos_vm_install_dmg.sh`